# What happened to the Members/Methods combobox in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio 2008, I can see a combo box containing the members/methods defined in my class at the top of the code window:

[image]

However, I cannot see this in Visual Studio 2010! Was it removed? Can I get it back?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's still there, you must have just inadvertently turned it off. To turn it back on, follow these easy steps:

1. From the "Tools" menu, select "Options".
2. Expand the "Text Editor" heading.
3. Select your language of choice (e.g., C# or VB.NET).
4. Check the box labeled "Navigation bar".

[image]